# 'Console' does not contain a definition for 'ReadKey' in asp.net 5 console App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I am creating a Simple application in **ASP.NET 5 Console in VS2015 CTP**. For the below line of code

```
// Wait for user input
            Console.ReadKey();
```

I am getting error *'Console' does not contain a definition for 'ReadKey'*. Also i am getting a Suggestion as `ASP.Net 5.0-Available ASP.NET Core 5.0- Not available`. ReadKey keyword is no more used ? what does that suggestion means i need to add some reference ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically, `Console.ReadKey` *is* available in the full framework, but *isn't* available in .NET Core. That's why it's saying it's "Available" for ASP.NET 5.0 (building against the full framework) but "Not available" for ASP.NET Core 5.0 (building against CoreCLR).

Either stop using it, or only build against the full framework - edit your `project.json` file to remove the "core" option from your `frameworks` property. (Exactly what it will be called will depend on which version of ASP.NET 5 you're using. It may be `dnxcore50` for example.)

Comment: You just beat me to it!

Comment: @JonSkeet You mean i have to use normal console application ?

Comment: @Shrivallabh: No, I mean that you can edit your project.json to remove the attempt to build against .NET Core.

Comment: That worked @JonSkeet. This means if i build with both Core and Full Framework then i should only use those methods which both of them support?

Comment: @Shrivallabh: Yes - or use conditional compilation (`#if ...`) if necessary.

Comment: @JonSkeet: sorry for the newbie question, what would I put as the condition for the if statement to only run for the full ASP.NET 5.0?

Comment: @Nathan: You'd need to use `#if` and define a compiler preprocessor symbol for just that build. Haven't looked at how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Jon, and for those wondering, it looks like you just use the all caps version number as the condition (ex: #if DNX451) the documentation is here: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/dotnetcore.html#building-applications-with-net-core