# Why does the Visual Studio 2013 console window always close right after I run a program?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Every time I run a program in Visual Studio 2013 it closes the console window directly after it asks for any more input from the user for the last time it's told to. I have put `return 0;` at the end of it, but that too doesn't fix it. And yes, I always run it with the StartWithoutDebugging option (ctrl + F5) as many people have resolved it with.

I've searched high and low for an answer on this webiste but with no avail. Any answers it seems that anyone gives is for a different IDE or I have already implemented it.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Because the program is finished, and as such it's closing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop C# console applications of closing automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512821/how-to-stop-c-sharp-console-applications-of-closing-automatically)

Comment: You need to understand that this is not a VS13 behavior. This is the behavior of what happens when a method ends, and in this case I suspect the Main. Roughly put, when the Main method ends, so does the program.