# Timer not starting

Tags: c#, events, timer

So i want to check the current `time` every second and if `seconds == 0` raise `event` and show current time:

```
using System.Timers;

public delegate void TimeHandler(object sender, TimeEventArgs e);

public class Clock
{
    private Timer timer;
    public event TimeHandler CurrentTime;

    public Clock()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        int sec = time.Second;
        if (sec == 0)
            if (CurrentTime != null)
                CurrentTime(this, new TimeEventArgs(time));
    }
}

public class TimeEventArgs
{
    public readonly DateTime Time;

    public TimeEventArgs(DateTime time)
    {
        Time = time;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Clock clock = new Clock();
clock.CurrentTime += Clock_CurrentTime;
clock.Start();

private static void Clock_CurrentTime(object sender, TimeEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Time.ToShortTimeString());
}
```

But it seems like the timer elapsed not starting.

Comment: you are not calling timer.start(); assuming that timer is a instance of Stopwatch

Comment: using System.Timers;

Comment: Your method timer_Elapsed itself will be called every seconds so you can directly write from there

Comment: timer_Elapsed never started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `timer_Elapsed` mismatches `currentTime` and `CurrentTime`. If you check the delegate you should use the capitalized name of the handler.

You could make certain that the `Elapsed` handler is called by setting a breakpoint in it or put a log message directly there, right at the beginning.

Finally, `Clock_CurrentTime` will only be called once per minute.

Comment: Please see my edit, my console application still ends without get into this timer_elapsed method

Comment: Sure, if you don't keep the console app running: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512821/how-to-stop-c-sharp-console-applications-from-closing-automatically?rq=1 --  Just let it wait for keypress: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891538/listen-for-key-press-in-net-console-app?rq=1