# Console.ReadKey() doesn't take effect

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a problem! When I run this code in c# console application:

```
class Program  
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)        
    {    
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");            
        Console.Readkey();
    }
}
```

.. it doesn't take effect and the program automatically closes ... What to do?

Comment: What do you want the program to do?

Comment: @Wudge I think that's pretty clear

Comment: You capitalisation is wrong. Console.ReadKey or Console.ReadLine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop C# console applications from closing automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512821/how-to-stop-c-sharp-console-applications-from-closing-automatically)

Comment: Then you're pressing F5 for too long.

Comment: The code you've posted won't even compile. Once the typo is fixed, that code *will* wait until you press a key. My guess is the problem is in some of your code that you haven't posted.

Comment: @Equalsk: How is it a duplicate of that? The question is effectively why the accepted *answer* of that doesn't work...

Comment: My reasoning was that if he'd just read a question about preventing closure of the console he wouldn't have even needed to ask this question.

Comment: I want this console to wait until i press a key ..

Comment: @GiurgiuAron ...We know

Comment: i'm new here , so take me ease ! :)))

Comment: @GiurgiuAron Please read the comments, this has been answered. You've just made a typo, it should be `ReadKey` (note the two capital letters for R and K), you have typed `Readkey`.

Comment: i work in visual studio 2013

Comment: it doesn't work ... when i click run , just prompt for 1 second and then disappier , sorry for my english :) , i speak romanian :)

Comment: In VS Options for Build and Run (Tools-Options, search for Build and Run), is one of the combo box set to Launch Old Version? Change it to Do not Launch. You're probably running the old compilable version

Comment: If the app is not working when using `ReadKey` then something else is causing the issue and you haven't posted enough information in your question for anybody to answer properly. Sorry.

Comment: i set it to "do not launch" , but it stil closing

Comment: sorry ,but it stil not working :( , you'll are amaizing but something went wrong ... i feel your help .. Thanks however

Comment: What happen if you add a breakpoint in the Console.ReadKey() line?

Comment: @GiurgiuAron ofc, it's not working ... edit your question and post the exact code you have, without typos.

Comment: this is all programm , i just maked a class upside , but i didn't use it , it doesn't affect ... it's just a new project console application in the namespace Natural_TextData_Processing

Comment: @GiurgiuAron try to make another new project and test it out again. Without changing anything, except the code on the Main function

Comment: why it disappier ????  i can't explain .. oh ... how can i learn all c# language if i can run a little terrible command   ... i just must to make the visual studio from 0 to understand it

Comment: great , finely !!!! wow , it works :)

Comment: i made another project :)) thanks , that's good !!! :)

Comment: ... be careful now :)

Comment: sorry for understand(less) :)

Comment: i think i made some corupted actions ! Initialy made a project on desktop and then arhived and moved to D: ... than appear an error : the specific link name too long ... i put it agine on desktop , after compiled it in d :)))

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo in your code so you are probably running an older build

Change

```
Console.Readkey
```

To

```
Console.ReadKey
```

Answer (score -3):

> Add following Code instead of  Console.ReadKey()
>   It will hold the screen on monitor.

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Why is ReadLine any better than ReadKey?

Comment: So will `Console.ReadKey()` if using the correct capitalisation which the OP has not done.

Comment: because Readkey() accept the Character and return ASCII value of that character .   And  ReadLine() accept the String and return the string as well.

Comment: @GovindTupkar but how is that helpful? The OP's question clearly has this line `Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");` not only do they not care about getting anything returned, they specifically want *one* character